# Untrusted Location

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, roaming-profile, login, logon-scripts

I've recently switched to roaming profiles in an XP and Windows 7 environment and also changed the login script.  Can anyone tell me where I would find the info regarding messages that appear when people are launching various in-house apps :

**This program is from an untrusted location, Click Run or Cancel.**

The programs run but users need to click 'Run' first.

Answer (score 2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303650